# Display a nested image with paperclip and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, show, nested-forms

I have two models :
Post and Picture

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :picture, :dependent => :destroy


accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['pictures'].nil? }

end
```

and

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :posts 

has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Picture has a paperclip attachment : image

I created a nested form but i'm not able to know if my picture is saved correctly since i can't display in the show page.

Here is my form :

```
 <%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :brand %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :brand %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :model %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :model %>
  </div>


  <div class="field"><%= f.fields_for :picture do |p| %>

    <%= p.file_field :image %>


      <% end %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My show page :

```
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


  <%= @post.picture.each do |pic|  %>

    <%= image_tag pic.image.url(:medium) %>
  <% end %>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Brand:</strong>
  <%= @post.brand %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Model:</strong>
  <%= @post.model %>
</p>



<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

The post controller :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.picture.build

  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        if params[:image]

          params[:image].each { |image|
          @post.picture.create(image: image)
          }
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

     # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :brand, :model,   picture_attributes: [ :id, :post_id, :image, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

When i heat create post, i have no error the post is rendered but instead of having the image displayed i have this : "[]" ?

Terminal output :

```
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
  Picture Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 8]]
```

Is there something i did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have is that you've referenced your associations incorrectly:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pictures #-> plural
end

#app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post #-> singular

   has_attached_file :image
   validates :image, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
end
```

You can see about the [association names](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) here:

[image]

A pro tip is to use the [`paperclip_defaults`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults) options in your `application.rb`:

```
#config/application.rb
...
config.paperclip_defaults: {
    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
}
```

This will allow you to set the "defaults" for all implementations of Paperclip in your app, which can be overridden as you need in each model. Just makes it less messy I find...

---

In regards your error, you have all the pieces in place; I think the issue is your association names (see above).

This is what I would have:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @post = Post.new
      @post.pictures.build #-> plural
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.new post_params
      @post.save
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :brand, :model,   picture_attributes: [:image, :_destroy])
   end
end
```

You'd then be able to use the following form:

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, multipart: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |p| %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

This should submit to your db properly; to display the images, you can use the following:

```
#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<% @post.pictures.each do |picture| %>
   <%= image_tag picture.image.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Still the same behaviour, no error when validating the post but i can't display the image, i have this  "[]"

Comment: Are the images in the db?

Comment: how to check it ? (sorry i m very new with ROR)

Comment: Do you not have something like `PHPMyAdmin` installed?

Comment: i m in dev mode on cloud9, a web ide...When i use the rails c, and typing : Post.last.pictures i have this : > Post.last.pictures.count
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 11]]

Comment: And what is returned?

Comment: when the show appears terminal is : Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  Picture Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 11]]
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 72.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Comment: that's just the SQL query it seems - does it not give you the ability to see what's returned?

Comment: Ok they are not in the DB, note that my post table doesn't have a picture_id column. Do you think that s the thing ?